# how to load below execute by gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I have to start my own binary with below command:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path path executable arg1
```

I want to debug this binary by gdb,

I tried with below, but failed.

gdb --args arg1

> $ set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH path
>
> $ run

not work.
the output is below:

```
During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

so, what can I load it to gdb.

Comment: "I have to start my own binary with below command: ..." -- why?

Comment: "gdb --args arg1" do you mean "gdb --args executable arg1"?

Comment: Can you start your binary with "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path executable arg1"?